# QGIS Expression: Finding DEM value at point where two lines on different layers intersect

Tags: qgis, raster, intersection, expression, query

I've been working a while on this and I'm sure I'm missing something. I have to sets of lines on a DEM, and I need to call a raster value where they intersect. I can get it to where I am getting the centroid value of the line with this

```
raster_value( 'DEM-test',
1,
make_point(
x($geometry), y($geometry)
)
)
```

And so I know I need a point instead of a line feature, and I wrote this:

```
raster_value( 'DEM-test',
1,
make_point(
x(intersection(collect($geometry),
             aggregate('New scratch layer2','collect',$geometry,                    intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent))))), 
             
y(intersection(collect($geometry),
             aggregate('New scratch layer2','collect',$geometry,
                    intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))))
)
)
```

Which does not work. DEM-test is the raster and New scratch layer2 is the second scratch layer. What am I missing? I know I can do this through other means, but it must be through a QGIS expression.

Answer (score 5):

You get the intersection point of two lines in the same layer with this expression:

```
 intersection ($geometry,overlay_intersects(@layer,$geometry)[0])
```

So the expression to get the elevation is:

```
raster_value('DEM', 1,  intersection ($geometry, overlay_intersects( @layer, $geometry)[0]))
```

If the crossing lines are on different layers, replace `@layer` (the variable stands for the current layer) with the name of the layer that contains the second line.

*Using the expression as input to create a dynamic label:*
[image]

---

**Edit**:

For a line that crosses another line on another layer several times, use this expression to get an array of elevation values for each crossing point, ordered along the input line from start- to end point. Convert to a string (text) with `array_to_string()`. Be aware: [`geom_to_array()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#geometries-to-array) is a [new function available since QGIS 3.28](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog328/index.html#feature-make-valid-and-geom-to-array-functions).

*Blue line labeled with the expression from below; red points with labels show intersection points as individual point layer for control purpose here:*
[image]

```
array_foreach(
    with_variable(
        'points',
        geometries_to_array(  
            array_foreach(
                overlay_intersects ('line1',$geometry),
                intersection ($geometry,@element)
            )[0]
        ),
        array_sort(
            array_foreach(
                @points,
                line_locate_point ($geometry, @element)
            )
        )
    ),
    raster_value(
        'dem',
        1,
        line_interpolate_point($geometry,@element)
        
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, looking for two lines in two different layers.

Comment: OK, then simply replace `@layer` with the name of the layer containing the second line.

Comment: By jove, I think you've got it! Thanks, that works. And it was simpler than I was attempting.

Comment: You're welcome. Please be adviced that this side tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: @DrewGIS - please accept Babels answer and select the checkmark if this answer helped you.

Answer (score 4):

Lets say we have three layers: `lineA`, `lineB` and `DEM`.

1. On `lineA` apply a Symbology using a `Geometry Generator` with `Point / MultiPoint` as the Geometry type.

```
intersection(
    collect($geometry),
    aggregate(
        'lineB',
        'collect',
        $geometry,                    
        intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent))
    )
)
```

2. As Markers use a `Font Marker` and a `Simple Marker`
3. For the `Font Marker` use `raster_value('DEM',1,geometry_n( $geometry, @geometry_part_num ))` as the expression for the Character(s) property - this will label at the intersections of each point based on the raster value of your DEM.

[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can do it in the geometry generator, but I need to do it in a different expression without the ability to simple define it as a point.